# GCC Inline Assembly to Binary

Tags: gcc, assembly, compilation

In C or C++ you can implement inline assembly instructions by doing the following:

```
asm("assembly code");
```

or

```
__asm__ ("assembly code");
```

Example:

```
asm("movl %ebx, %eax"); /* moves the contents of ebx register to eax */
__asm__("movb %ch, (%ebx)"); /* moves the byte from ch to the memory pointed by ebx */
```

And then you can generate an interaction to exchange values between your assembly code, and your C/C++ variables: More on that [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15971/Using-Inline-Assembly-in-C-C).

My question is: Is each inline assembly instruction directly translated to its binary counterpart by the compiler? Or is this just a sort of "Emulation"? What this is all amounted to, is that I wanted to know if you are actually accessing the processor's registers or all the data handled within the code is stored in the stack, emulating assembly instructions. Sorry if the question is dumb.

Comment: GCC's Inline assembler does simple substitution (if using an extended assembler template) but outputs the instructions in a single _ASM_ statement as is into the code. So yes, once compiled into the code it will be using the real registers. This of course is assuming the program isn't being run in an emulator.

Comment: thanks, just had the doubt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

When you use the **'__asm__'** or the **'asm'** keywords, GCC/G++ parses the string into assembly instructions. If you use **'extended assembly'**, that is when you include the colons after your string so as to make your variables interact with the **'input/output'** of the registers, the inline assembler does simple substitution, just like in the following example:

---

> __asm__ ("\
>       add %ebx,%eax;\
>       mov %ebx,%ecx;\
>       " : "=c"(output_variable) : "b"(first_operand),"a"(second_operand) : /*Nothing needed here*/);

*Note the backslash at the end of each assembly line. It is to escape the line jump so as to use one single pair of quotes to englobe all the assembly code. Also, in order to help the inline assembly parser, each assembly instruction must end with a semicolon*

---

After the instruction/s in between the double quotes, you can add three colons, between the first two, you declare the variables that are going to receive the output. Note the **"=c"(output_variable)** means that the value stored in the **ecx** register at the end, will be forwarded to the variable between **()**.

Between the last two colons, you declare the variables/values that are going to serve as an input, so at the begining of the code, the value between parenthesis is assigned to the register represented with the letter between quotes (use comas for more than one input).

After the last colon, goes a list of clobbered registers. However this is optional and useless in this particular case. More about the whole GCC Inline Assembly [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15971/Using-Inline-Assembly-in-C-C).

So, in summary, the execution goes like this:

- Substitution of input values, if any, into the corresponding registers
- Translation from assembly into binary
- Load output into the assigned variables, if any

---

So the short answer would be **yes**, once the code is compiled into machine language, the conversion will be 1 on 1, just like a common assembler, and thus it will be using the real registers.

---

Comment: I forgot to say that the backslash at the end of each assembly line, is to escape the line jump so as to use one single pair of quotes. And also, each assembly instruction must end with a semicolon, thought this is just to help the inline assembly parser

Comment: Should also point out that your example adds ebx to eax and stores result in eax. You move ebx to ecx which in effect sets ebx to the contents of first_operand not to the added values.

Comment: Semicolon isn't required on each line. A `\n` newline character will do. Preferable is `\n\t` which will format more nicely if you use _GCC_ with the `-S` option to output the assembler code generated by _GCC_ .You can avoid the line continuation characters altogether if you quote each line separately. One error in your code is that with extended inline assembler register names require `%%` not `%`. This would also work: `__asm__ ("add %%ebx,%%eax\n\t" "mov %%ebx,%%ecx" : "=c"(output_variable) : "b"(first_operand),"a"(second_operand) : );`

Comment: What might be more readable is to assign each operand a name and use the name inside the extended assembly template. Something like `__asm__("add %[iop1],%[iop2]\n\t"
                      "mov %[iop1],%[ovar]"
                      : [ovar]"=c"(output_variable) : [iop1]"b"(first_operand),[iop2]"a"(second_operand) : );`

Comment: If david wohlferd comes by he would probably [advise against inline assembly](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm) when not necessary, and since `add` changes the flags it is a good habit to add `"cc"` to the clobber list (the way _GCC_ with x86 works this isn't actually necessary)